# Limit to number of Broadcasts on a cluster?

Tags: c, mpi, cluster-computing, openmpi, slurm

I have a problem with a loop containing mpi broadcast line. After 1000th iterations, the broadcast line stops or hangs the execution (waiting for the transmission presumably).

See the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int  aa = 0, size = 10000;
    int  my_rank; /* rank of process */
    int  smessage = 9, rmessage = 9;        /* storage for message */

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    if(my_rank !=0) {
        for(aa=1;aa<size;aa++) {
            MPI_Bcast(&rmessage, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("rec message(i=%d)=%d\n", aa, rmessage);
        }
    }
    else {
        for(aa=1;aa<size;aa++) {
            smessage=aa;
            printf("send message(i=%d)=%d\n", aa, smessage);
            MPI_Bcast(&smessage, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

when I run it with

```
mpicc -openmp -fopenmp example_code.c -o example_prog
mpirun -n 3 example_prog
```

I get the expected output (up to some rearrangements)

```
sent message(i=1)=1
rec message(i=1)=1
rec message(i=1)=1
...
sent message(i=9999)=9999
rec message(i=9999)=9999
rec message(i=9999)=9999
```

However, when I send it to my university cluster using SLURM's sbatch and a script containing

```
mpirun -n 3 --loadbalance --cpus-per-proc 24 ./example_prog
```

(I'm using OpenMPI 1.6.5) I get the program either hanged in the middle of the loop or gets automatically terminated by the job handler. The output is

```
sent message(i=1)=1
rec message(i=1)=1
rec message(i=1)=1
...

rec message(i=9999)=999
rec message(i=9999)=999
sent message(i=9999)=1000
```

It clearly stops in the "middle" of the loop. Would you have any ideas as to what causes this error or how to avoid this error?

Thank you so much!

Comment: This seems odd. Is it always after the same amount iterations? Are you sure about the last three lines of a wrong output?

Comment: I ran exactly your code and it works fine in our slurm cluster with openmpi 1.8

Comment: This pattern can generate a lot of unexpected messages. A workaround in Open MPI was to use the `coll/sync` module. Long story short, it automatically inserts `MPI_Barrier()` every n collectives. Which version of Open MPI are you running on your university cluster ?

Comment: @Gilles I'm using Open MPI 1.6.5.

Comment: This is an obsolete version and you should consider upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: @Gilles I'll now use MPI 3.0.1, and MPI_Barrier before each broadcast to see if it improves the situation.

Comment: you might want to give `mpirun --mca coll ^sync ...` a try (both 1.6.5 and 3.0.1)